# flutter assets http image did not load HTTP request failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

error is

HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://165.232.77.146:8069/web/image?model=product.template&field=imag

fetching image on odoo image in http not load in flutter https image load odoo all other data load like image url show console when i click opens in chrome but did not load in flutter app
image: NetworkImage("$theUrl/web/image?model=product.template&field=image_1920&id=${provider.allProducts[index].id}",),

Comment: 404 usually means the item isn't found... Can you check if the url is proper? Also what exactly are you trying to do? Where's the image? On the server or in local....

Comment: its on odoo and when i log that image it shows in console and when I click on that image than it will open image in chrome 
but did not load in fluttter

Comment: Are you trying on flutter web? This might help => https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/web-images

Comment: no on flutter app

Comment: I think your url isn't encoded properly... Make sure all your parameters are provided properly... Also can you share the url that opens well in chrome?